# How to run a Docker image inside your EC2 container?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have an EC2 instance with the following docker image inside:

```
REPOSITORY       TAG      IMAGE ID
grant/docker-app hookedup b99f4ad
```

In my local machine I have been using `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up` to get the servers running.

How do I get the image on the EC2 instance running?

I login to AWS with Amazon Linux AMI. I've installed docker and docker-compose on it. I can see the image but I don't know how to start it.

The docker repo is on hub.docker.com. I pulled it from there.

I have tried:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 grant/docker-app:hookedup
```

which outputs some string: `cdf4c4035e0...30b4d0881d635ecdac6f3`

I have also tried:

```
docker-compose build grant/docker-app:hookedup
```

which outputs: `Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any`

I have also tried

```
docker run --rm -p 3000:3000 grantspilsbury/docker-app:hookedup
```

which gives the output:

```
> docker-sample-app@0.1.0 start /usr/src/app
> react-scripts start

Could not find a required file.
  Name: index.html
  Searched in: /usr/src/app/public
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! docker-sample-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

If I run docker ps or docker ps -a I get:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172...-26 ~]$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
[ec2-user@ip-172...-26 ~]$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                       COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                         PORTS               NAMES
0ca69ff467bc        grant/docker-app:hookedup   "npm start"         24 minutes ago      Exited (1) 24 minutes ago                          happy_archimedes
2a01050f3bb6        grant/docker-app:hookedup   "npm start"         About an hour ago   Exited (1) About an hour ago                       wonderful_rosalind
```

If I run docker logs 0ca69ff467bc I get the outpu:

```
Could not find a required file.
  Name: index.html
  Searched in: /usr/src/app/public
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! docker-sample-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the docker-sample-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-01-27T03_35_55_030Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Have you considered using [AWS Elastic Container Services](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/) to manage the container startup for you?

Comment: Also note that running `run -d` is running in detached mode - the string you see is the unique id of that container. If you do `docker ps` (or `docker ps -a` to see both running and stopped containers), do you see anything?

Comment: @MrDuk thanks. I have added to the question with docker ps -a log. I am looking into ECS now. Another rabbit hole.

Comment: can you post the output from `docker logs 0ca69ff467bc`?

Comment: @MrDuk I have added the output of docker log

Answer (score 0):

There is a nodejs problem inside you container. Run

```
docker run -it --rm -p 3000:3000 --entrypoint sh grantspilsbury/docker-app:hookedup
```

Inspect what you have inside the container, especially `/usr/src/app/public`. And, perhaps, work with your developer.

In my opinion, you have an nodejs react app in the container. In the WORKDIR, there is package.json. However, the `index.html` could not be found indicates that not all files are copied into the image, or the app is searching in a wrong path.